# Change tabBarIcon when a redux state changes

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have defined `navigationOptions` under `App.js` for a flow like so:

**App.js**

```js
const intimationsFlow = createStackNavigator({
  Feed: FeedContainer,
  Edit: EditContainer
});

intimationsFlow.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let tabBarVisible = true;
  if (navigation.state.index > 0)
    tabBarVisible = false;

  return {
    title: '',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
      const { pushNotificationSeen } = store.getState();
      console.log('pushNotificationSeen', pushNotificationSeen);

      let i;
      if(pushNotificationSeen) {
        if (focused) {
          i = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={'bell'} size={29} color={'#3780BE'} />
        } else {
          i = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={'bell'} size={29} color={'#393939'} />
        }
      } else {
        if (focused) {
          updatePushNotificationSeen(true);
          i = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={'bell'} size={29} color={'#3780BE'} />
        } else {
          i = <><FontAwesomeIcon icon={'bell'} size={29} color={'#393939'} /><Badge status="error" badgeStyle={{ position: 'absolute', top: -26, right: -13 }} /></>
        }
      }

      return i;
    },
    tabBarVisible
  };
};

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  ResolveAuth: ResolveAuthScreen,
  mainFlow
});

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default () => {
  return <Provider store={store}>
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <App ref={navigatorRef => { setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) }} />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  </Provider>
};
```

I want to update the tabBarIcon based on whether a push notification has already been seen or not. If the push notification has not already been seen then I show a badge instead.

The problem here is that I could only fetch the state when there is an activity on the tab bar. But what I want is that whenever the status of `pushNotificationSeen` is updated, the tarBarIcon should get re-rendered.

Please suggest if it is possible otherwise how could it be achieved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a decent solution.

What really I wanted was a way to access redux store from the *React Navigation component*. React navigation components like any other react components can be [**connect**ed](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html#use-a-component-that-is-connect-ed) to the redux store. However, in this particular case, in order to connect the react navigation component, what I wanted was to create an [custom extended navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html#extending-navigators) as per this [suggestion](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5821#issuecomment-484203010).

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Badge } from 'react-native-elements';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

import FeedContainer from '../../screens/feed/FeedContainer';
import EditContainer from '../../screens/edit/EditContainer';
import { updatePushNotificationSeen } from '../../store/push-notification-seen/actions';

const IntimationsFlow = createStackNavigator({
    Feed: FeedContainer,
    Edit: EditContainer
});

class IntimationsFlowNavigator extends Component {

    static router = IntimationsFlow.router;

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        let tabBarVisible = true;
        if (navigation.state.index > 0)
            tabBarVisible = false;

        return {
            title: '',
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                let i;
                if (!navigation.state.params || navigation.state.params.pushNotificationSeen) {
                    if (focused)
                        i = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={'bell'} size={29} color={'#3780BE'} />;
                    else
                        i = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={'bell'} size={29} color={'#393939'} />;
                } else {
                    if (focused)
                        i = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={'bell'} size={29} color={'#3780BE'} />;
                    else
                        i = <>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={'bell'} size={29} color={'#393939'} />
                            <Badge status="error" badgeStyle={{ position: 'absolute', top: -26, right: -13 }} />
                        </>;
                }

                return i;
            },
            tabBarVisible
        };
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const { navigation, pushNotificationSeen } = this.props;
        if (pushNotificationSeen !== prevProps.pushNotificationSeen)
            navigation.setParams({ pushNotificationSeen });
    }

    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        return <>
            <NavigationEvents
                onDidFocus={() => { if (!this.props.pushNotificationSeen) updatePushNotificationSeen(true) }}
                onDidBlur={() => { if (!this.props.pushNotificationSeen) updatePushNotificationSeen(true) }}
            />
            <IntimationsFlow navigation={navigation} />
        </>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ pushNotificationSeen }) => {
    return { pushNotificationSeen };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(IntimationsFlowNavigator);
```

Every time there was an update in the props. I was setting new value for `navigation.state.params.pushNotificationSeen` like so `navigation.setParams({ pushNotificationSeen });` in the `componentDidUpdate` [lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) so as to use it in the `navigationOptions` static method. (We can't directly access components props in the `navigationOptions` method since it is a static member).

Any side-effects that are needed to be performed on focus/blur of the tab can be achieved via [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) as per this [suggestion](https://github.com/react-navigation/tabs/issues/171#issuecomment-533110280).

Answer (score 0):

you have to listen push notifications change in reducer at componentWillReceiveProps

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    {...}
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: ({ state }) => `there is ${state.params && state.params.pushNotificationSeen ? state.params.pushNotificationSeen : ''}`,
        {...}
    }
    {...}
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.pushNotificationSeen) {
            this.props.navigation.setParams({ pushNotificationSeen });
        }
    }
}

const connectedSuperMan = connect(state => ({ pushNotificationSeen: state.ReducerYo.pushNotificationSeen }))(YourComponent);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I have defined `navigationOptions` inside `App.js` file. How would I have it connected? It's defined outside any component.

Comment: in that case  YourComponent rename to App in app.js  and  use  export default  connect(state => ({ pushNotificationSeen: state.ReducerYo.pushNotificationSeen }))(App);

Comment: The `intimationsFlow` here is the Stack Navigator so the question is to how to access redux state from a navigation component?